# Sqlite or Core Data to update more then 50000 records

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I'm currently using coredata for my project. But when the api returns 54000 objects that the app need to update, the user has to wait almost 2 hours.
It's the major problem for the current project and I am thinking to use sqlite and not using coredata anymore to update  thousands of objects.

Is it a right decision to use Sqlite or is there any suggestion for CoreData? I can't decide. Any help will be great. Thank you.

Here is what I am doing:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *privateObjectContext = [AppDelegate appDelegate].privateManagedObjectContext;
    [privateObjectContext performBlock:^{

      int i = 1;
      for (NSDictionary *item in itemlist) {
            i++;

            [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                                        @"itemID == %@",[item objectForKey:@"item_id"]
                                        ]];
            NSError *error;
            NSMutableArray *inventories = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:
                                           [privateObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                               error:&error]];
            ItemManagedObject *itemMO;

            if(inventories.count){
                itemMO = inventories.firstObject;
            }else{
                itemMO = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ItemObject"
                                                       inManagedObjectContext:privateObjectContext];
            }
            [itemMO prepareWithDictionary:item];
        }

        NSError *error;
        if (![privateObjectContext save:&error]) {
            completionHandler(NO);
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what how you are currently updating the objects, that takes almost 2 hours? There may be ways to improve it, but it's impossible to say how without knowing what you're doing now.

Comment: Yes we need more detail, how are you processing the updates, how often do you save the context, have you used instruments to look for bottlenecks, post some code

Comment: @TomHarrington  I add the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 hours is very long. That's weird.

Yet you can massage your code by having core data do less work. Much less work.

1. **Perform a single fetch request** instead of 54K fetch requests
2. **Don't call a managed object property setter when a property value does not change**, so that no object is unnecessarily flagged as dirty, and Core Data does not have to perform a costly but useless update of the object when the "save" method is invoked.

This will dramatically reduce the amount of work performed by Core Data, and the performance of your application.

The second point is easy, but very verbose: compare each individual property values with dictionary values before calling setters.

The first point requires an algorithm change:

Perform a single fetch request, sorted by id (with [NSFetchRequest setSortDescriptors:])

Sort dictionaries by id (with [NSArray sortedArray...])

Synchronize the two sorted lists (it is paramount that both lists are sorted):

```
NSEnumerator *itemMOEnum = [itemMOs objectEnumerator];
NSEnumerator *dicEnum = [dictionaries objectEnumerator];
ItemManagedObject *itemMO = [itemMOEnum nextObject];
NSDictionary *itemDic = [dicEnum nextObject];

while (itemDic) {
    NSComparisonResult comparison = itemMO ? [itemDic[@"item_id"] compare:itemMO.itemID] : NSOrderedAscending;
    switch (comparison) {
        case NSOrderedSame:
            // id present in both lists: update
            [itemMO prepareWithDictionary:itemDic];

            itemMO = [itemMOEnum nextObject];
            itemDic = [dicEnum nextObject];
            break;

        case NSOrderedAscending: {
            // id present only in dictionaries: create
            itemMO = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ItemObject"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:privateObjectContext];
            [itemMO prepareWithDictionary:itemDic];

            itemDic = [dicEnum nextObject];
        } break;

        case NSOrderedDescending:
            // id present only in managed object: delete or do nothing
            itemMO = [itemMOEnum nextObject];
            break;
    }
}

while (itemMO) {
    // id present only in managed object: delete or do nothing
    itemMO = [itemMOEnum nextObject];
}
```

And save.

Finally, maybe SQLite will be faster (see https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/wiki/Performance for an attempt at comparing the performance of Core Data with SQLite libraries).

**But SQLite won't turn a slow algorithm into a fast one**.

Comment: Thank you soo much. It takes 7 minutes. I ve never thought using NSEnumerator. Sorry for late response.

Answer (score 1):

Core Data provides `NSBatchUpdateRequest` which allows you to make updates directly on the persistent store without involving instantiating and processing managed objects in memory.

You should run this code using the core data performance instrument as well. If `itemList` contains 54,000 objects then you are performing 54,000 fetches to the persistent store to check a single ID each time. It would be far faster to fetch all of the IDs up front and then check the results in memory than to perform repeated fetch requests - that code will be almost as slow in raw SQL as it is in Core Data.

This code also looks wrong:

```
ItemManagedObject *itemMO;

if(itemMO.count){
```

It's never going to pass that if test, unless you've missed a line somewhere.

Comment: ups.while I was editing my code for stackoverflow question , i wrote it wrong. But each 3 or 4 columns can have different values. Non of them are same. So NSBatchUpdateRequest is useless for this situation. But thanks in anyway. With answers I learned more about difference between sqlite coredata with a better explanations. So it will be good for me to convert the structure into using sqlite from coredata.

Answer (score 0):

I've never redone a core data project in sqlite or visa versa. So I cannot tell you whether there is a performance difference or not/

However the 54k = 2 hours thing sounds very strange. You talk about an API which makes me suspect a server is involved, your question is about databases. Certainly 2 hours sounds way too long and makes me wonder whether you have issues with the core design of your database. For example, lack of indexes. Depending on your queries and database, a single update could be triggering all sorts of heavy duty processing.

Another though is why are you processing this column of data on a device. It's a lot to handle and I wonder if there are ways to reduce the volume down, selectively do updates or perhaps even better - move it to a server.

I think you need to rethink your question. Provide more context about the database, exactly what you are doing with it and why.

Comment: Like @jrturton said "If itemList contains 54,000 objects then you are performing 54,000 fetches to the persistent store to check a single ID each time." . I didn't know this working system of coredata. I guess the answer of 2 hours is this.

Answer (score 0):

CoreData is not a database manager but a object graph and persistent manager. CoreData can store its objects in a sqlite database but also in XML files or binary file (the developer chooses the option best suited to its needs).

The main difference between CoreData and a database manager is that to access an object with CoreData, CoreData need to instantiate the objective-C/Swift corresponding object.

Sqlite can access part of data without having to extract the full record containing the data.

And then, CoreData need to maintain the relational graph between objects (the relationships between 2 CoreData classes, and in general, in both ways).

So, when updating 54k objects, you ask CoreData to instantiate 54k objects (in memory) and to eventually update their relationships.

That is very heavy work for CoreData on mobile.

Perhaps your CoreData model is not correctly optimized.
Perhaps you should save the CoreData context regularly and flush CoreData scratchpad (the part of memory containing actually read or updated objects).

But in my experience, CoreData is not suited to heavy data work.

Re-implementing your needs with sqlite can be quite some work if you want to be able to re-instantiate your classe objects from sqlite records and manage quite automatic relationship, but it is doable. I did it on some projects. This add the benefit to have a model object that is more shareable with other platform as Android for instance, as sqlite is available on many platforms.

One more thing: sqlite is more suited to be used from multiple threads. CoreData is more touchy about this, and need one context by thread, and eventually, some contexts synchronization.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, now i understand core data and sqlite differences better. It sometimes better to ask and get more opinions to understand the problem and learn things then just searching on web and try to get an idea(I searched but now I understnad better)