# Sync data with ios swift local Database and server

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I am trying to build an iOS swift application that uses SQLITE and syncs it to my PHP backend server .

I can build API that reads and write data from server . 
I can read and write data with swift from server making HTTP requests .

What I am trying to accomplish here is : saving data to local database and sync it to the server database , the local database is user specific and the server database contains all users data .

Local DB

```
--------------------------
| maint item | due date | 
| abc        | 29-3-2018
| DNA        | 24-1-2017
| boy        | 17-2-2017
--------------------------
```

Server DB

```
---------------------------
| Maine item | due date | user 
| abc        | 29-3-2018| Jane 
| DNA        | 24-1-2017| Jane
| boy        | 17-2-2017| Jane
| amc        | 22-7-2017| cameleon
```

How can I achieve that in swift and if possible please post example project .

Comment: Will you send those rows of data as array of items in JSON format?

Comment: I have no reason for doing or not doing that .

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of scenarios, but I recommend this one:

Separate the layers of the project I recommend VIPER, Clean swift or ReSwift architecture.

After that your best friend will be the Interactor ( Thunk in ReSwift), there you will navigate the API and Database managers.

example :

If I have internet, download info from the API check If there is a similar object in the local database and present the new one. If the local is new update the API (or not .. :) ).

If I don't have internet show the local and update the date if the local one is changed...

Of course, there is no simple solution something more about the subject
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency

Comment: I was asking more of like a standard / simple way to do it . Like I thought it would have been done several times before and there's some sort of a standards example by the way I don't require SQLLite

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) to handle SQLite, just add it to your podfile:

```
pod "FMDB"
```

then install:

```
pod install
```

and import it in your bridging header:

```
#import <FMDB/FMDB.h>
```

The documentation is in Objective-C, but it's quite easy to translate that in swift. For example:

```
import FMDB

let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.libraryDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] + "/database.db"
let db = FMDatabase(path: path)
guard db.open() else {
            log.error("Unable to open database")
            return
}
db.executeStatements("CREATE TABLE ...")
```

Regarding the syncing process it's not so straightforward because you have to handle conflicts, unique IDs and so on.

If SQLite is not a requirement take a look at [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) or [SyncDB](https://github.com/SyncDB/Sync).

I hope this will help you!

Comment: Import the bridging header is not required if you `use_frameworks!` in your podfile. Then just `import FMDB`.

Comment: Actually SQLITE is not a requirement I'm looking at your suggestions .

Answer (score 0):

You can look at http://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift.

It is a Swift SQLite library that ships with sample code for synchronizing a JSON document and a database table: https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/blob/master/Playgrounds/JSONSynchronization.playground/Contents.swift

The output of this demo playground is below. You can see that its [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641715/sqlite-or-core-data-to-update-more-then-50000-records/39672352#39672352) is very efficient, and only applies the minimal amount of changes to the database:

```
-- Initial import {
--   "persons": [{
--     "id": 1,
--     "name": "Arthur"
--   }, {
--     "id": 2,
--     "name": "Barbara"
--   }, {
--     "id": 3,
--     "name": "Craig"
--   }, ]
-- }
SELECT * FROM persons ORDER BY id
INSERT INTO "persons" ("id", "name") VALUES (1,'Arthur')
INSERT INTO "persons" ("id", "name") VALUES (2,'Barbara')
INSERT INTO "persons" ("id", "name") VALUES (3,'Craig')

-- Import {
--   "persons": [{
--     "id": 2,
--     "name": "Barbie" (name is modified)
--   }, {
--     "id": 3,
--     "name": "Craig"  (not modified)
--   }, {
--     "id": 4,
--     "name": "Daniel" (new person)
--   }, ]
-- }    
SELECT * FROM persons ORDER BY id
DELETE FROM "persons" WHERE "id"=1
UPDATE "persons" SET "name"='Barbie' WHERE "id"=2
INSERT INTO "persons" ("id", "name") VALUES (4,'Daniel')
```